# In what paper was OCB2 introduced?

Tags: block-cipher, authenticated-encryption, tweakable-cipher, ocb

I've been working through "Cryptanalysis of OCB2: Attacks on Authenticity and Confidentiality" [1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/311.pdf) from earlier this year. My knowledge of OCB2 is pretty shallow though, and so I'm keen to study the scheme in depth before I continue.

From citations and searching around, it seems like OCB2 was introduced in a 2004 paper by Rogaway titled "Efficient instantiations of tweakable blockciphers and refinements to modes OCB and PMAC" [2](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-30539-2_2).

There aren't any explicit mentions of OCB2 in this paper though. Section 10 is titled "The OCB1 Authenticated-Encryption Scheme" and includes a description of "OCB1 with an ideal tweakable blockcipher". The scheme described in that section matches what I have read about OCB2.

I suppose the scheme only started being called OCB2 after the publication of the paper? Is that correct? If not, where can I find a description of OCB2?

Comment: listed here [What is the new attack on OCB2 and how does it work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63626/18298) the name comes with the standard?

Comment: I had read that thread before asking this question, but don't have access to the standard.

Comment: Wikipedia states as `OCB2 was first published in 2003, originally named authenticated-encryption mode, or advanced encryption mode (AEM)`

Comment: Thanks for your help kelalaka. Are you saying the answer to my question is "yes"?

Comment: If I don't miss a thing, yes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try get access to that standard and if I can, I'll write an answer up. Because I think there is value in making this link explicitly and in a way that can be found from a web search. 

I was personally pretty confused when I first read that paper and spent a bunch of time searching the internet under the assumption that I had downloaded the wrong PDF.

Comment: Good luck with that. AFAIK it is requiring subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: OCB2 was only named so after the fact. Confusingly, it was named OCB1 in the original 2004 paper.

You can find the OCB2 naming on the paper that introduces OCB3, [The Software Performance of Authenticated-Encryption Modes](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/ae.pdf):

> Integrated AE schemes were invented to improve performance of composed
> ones, but it has not been clear if they do. In the only comparative
> study to date [31], McGrew and Viega found that their composed scheme,
> GCM, was about as fast as, and sometimes faster than, the integrated
> scheme OCB [35] (hereinafter OCB1, to distinguish it from a subsequent
> variant we’ll call OCB2 [34]).

Another instance of the name transitioning is in two papers of Minematsu. The first one, [Improved Security Analysis of XEX and LRW Modes](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-74462-7_8) at SAC 2006, refers to the mode as the original OCB1; a later paper written in 2008, [Generalization and Extension of XEX* Mode](https://doi.org/10.1587/transfun.E92.A.517), already refers to it as OCB 2.0.

Finally, a [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7200227B2/en) filed by Rogaway in 2005 refers to the mode as OCB 2.0, which is presumably where the name change happened first.