# How do we find differentials in differential cryptanalysis when we don't the details about the S-boxes

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, differential-analysis, linear-cryptanalysis

I m new to cryptanalysis and trying to understand differential cryptanalysis. I have read the paper by Howard M. Heys. I understood the concept of differentials but I m not able to understand how to calculate the probability of a differential to occur when we don't know any information regarding the S-boxes.

It is given that, we give 2 inputs with a difference of say, x to an S-box and get outputs of difference y and in this way, we calculate the probabilities of all the differentials possible.

- But in general, the details of the S-boxes of a cipher are not disclosed (as far as I know, pls correct me if I m wrong), so how do we calculate these probabilities for each S-box?
- Can we somehow use differential cryptanalysis even if we don't know the details of S-boxes used in the cipher?

Comment: @kelalaka thanks for responding.  I have a follow-up question. Can we somehow use differential cryptanalysis even if we don't know the details of S-boxes used in the cipher?

Comment: @kelalaka thanks. I will definitely read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cryptography we play with the [Kerckhoffs's principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), in short, we can say that everything is known but not the secret key.

$$\text{There is no security with obscurity!}$$

Therefore;

> The details of the S-boxes of a cipher are not disclosed

**This is completely false**. The designers don't need to give the full details of their s-boxes, however, usually, they provide, as we see in the AES case;

- [The Design of Rijndael: The Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3662607689)

It is the attacker side to analyze even more than the designer to see a weakness in their design, or one may see errors on the calculations and provide the correct one, as in [OCB2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63626/18298), the history full of examples.

> Can we somehow use differential cryptanalysis even if we don't know the details of S-boxes used in the cipher?

Yes, that is possible, however, that will be impractical and will not provide a better attack than the bruteforce ( since it is a blackbox).

For the beginners of Differential and Linear attack a tutorial and a book is a must;

- [A Tutorial on Linear and Differential Cryptanalysis](https://ioactive.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/ldc_tutorial.pdf), by Howard M. Heys
- [The Block Cipher Companion](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-17342-4) book by Lars R. KnudsenMatthew and J.B. Robshaw

The [Sbox package of the SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/sbox.html) is the helper to analyze the S-Boxes.

And, if you want to study this field, always read the original paper, too;

- [Linear Cryptanalysis Method for DES Cipher](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48285-7_33.pdf), Matsui, 1994
- [Differential Cryptanalysis of DES-like Cryptosystems](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00630563.pdf), E. Biham and A. Shamir, 1991

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting case study here with the AES finalist [Twofish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twofish). Twofish uses key dependent S-boxes and so we do not know the S-boxes, only their means of construction. Nevertheless several papers have proposed differential attacks on the design ([Murphy and Robshaw](https://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/%7Esean/tf_dckdsb.pdf), [Shiho Moriai and Yiun Lisa Yin](http://www.schneier.com/twofish-analysis-shiho.pdf), [Ferguson](https://www.schneier.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/paper-twofish-impossible.pdf)).

Comment: Technically we know all of the design ( opposing to the OP's; we don't know the details ) that still doesn't make it a block-box design, right?